# Using GLEW in XCode 6- how to set it up?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glew

The following line gives an error on my Mac.

```
 #include <gl/glew.h>
```

I have linked the OpenGL and GLUT frameworks already. How can I link/make GLEW available?

Comment: You don't need GLEW on OS X. Pre-process out any code that references GLEW stuff by checking to make sure `__APPLE__` is undefined first.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific on how to do all this?

Comment: I thought I was? `#ifndef __APPLE__` <some glew code> `#endif`

Comment: I tried. That solution does not work.